# Hide/Show Div below select depending on whether an option is selected or not

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, visual-studio-2010

Basically I have a select:

```
<select id="SelectExample">
    <option value="no_selection">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="accessoires">Accessoires pour poubelles</option>
    <option value="chaises">Chaises</option>
    <option value="collecte">Collecte de déchets</option>
    <option value="poubelles">Poubelles</option>
</select>
```

Just below that is a div I want hidden if the value is `no_selection`

```
<div id="OtherDiv">
    <p><label for="poids">Poids (kg)</label><input type="text" id="poids" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
    <p><label for="prix">Prix (€)</label><input type="text" id="prix" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
    <p><label for="volume">Volume (l)</label><input type="text" id="volume" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
    <p><a href="#" class="no_label" id="sdd">Modifier les attributs…</a></p>
</div>
```

I've tried the previous JQuery and CSS examples I've found, but none seem to work for me, can anyone give me a good example of what to do as I'm a bit stuck, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

You need to [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) a [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to your select box, and on change, use [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to retrieve the value of the selected option, and show or hide depending on that. The jQuery [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method is great for that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="SelectExample">
            <option value="no_selection">&nbsp;</option>
            <option value="accessoires">Accessoires pour poubelles</option>
            <option value="chaises">Chaises</option>
            <option value="collecte">Collecte de déchets</option>
            <option value="poubelles">Poubelles</option>
        </select>

         <div id="OtherDiv">
            <p><label for="poids">Poids (kg)</label><input type="text" id="poids" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
            <p><label for="prix">Prix (€)</label><input type="text" id="prix" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
            <p><label for="volume">Volume (l)</label><input type="text" id="volume" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
            <p><a href="#" class="no_label" id="sdd">Modifier les attributs…</a></p>
        </div>

        <script>
            var showHideDiv = function (evt) {
                var selectedValue = jQuery(evt.target).val();
                var isSelected = selectedValue !== 'no_selection';
                jQuery("#OtherDiv").toggle(isSelected);
            }

            jQuery('#SelectExample').change(showHideDiv).trigger("change");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh I obviously misunderstood. I've reversed it (changed `===` for `!==`)

Comment: I've now changed it slightly, to add a `.trigger("change")` so that when you page initially loads the div will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="SelectExample" onChange="$('#OtherDiv').toggle($(this).val() != 'no_selection');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something of the following could work for you?

```
$("#SelectExample").change(
 function()
 {
  var that = $(this);

  if(that.val() == "no_selection"){
   $("#OtherDiv").show();
  }else{
   $("#OtherDiv").hide();
  }
 }
);
```

Just a simple OnChange event, then checking the value of the field - saying that, you don't even really need JQ for this..

Comment: Doing `that = $(this)` is completely pointless here. Don't clutter code with unnecessary things.

Comment: Instead of using show/hide use `toggle()` with a boolean. i.e. exactly what my code does except you are doing it by calling `change()` instead of in the HTML.

Comment: In this context - yes, it's pointless, but surely it's good practise to cache JQ objects, INCASE the code changes later to make extra use of `this`. As the changes of refractoring happening are slim

Comment: No, it's not good practice. You add extra lines which take extra time to read. If you use the jQuery object more than once, then add the cache variable then - not in advance.

Comment: Look - I'm just presenting different options - Your code is smaller, granted, but mine is easier to read - horses for courses.

Answer (score 0):

change display:

```
<select id="SelectExample" onchange="showOther(this.value)">
    <option value="no_selection">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="accessoires">Accessoires pour poubelles</option>
    <option value="chaises">Chaises</option>
    <option value="collecte">Collecte de déchets</option>
    <option value="poubelles">Poubelles</option>
</select>



<div id="OtherDiv" style="display:none">
    <p><label for="poids">Poids (kg)</label><input type="text" id="poids" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
    <p><label for="prix">Prix (€)</label><input type="text" id="prix" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
    <p><label for="volume">Volume (l)</label><input type="text" id="volume" class="medium" disabled="disabled"/></p>
    <p><a href="#" class="no_label" id="sdd">Modifier les attributs…</a></p>
</div>
```

and create a javascript function that handles your `onchange`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    showOther = function(val){
        if(val && val !='no_selection'){
            document.getElementById('OtherDiv').style.display = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('OtherDiv').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}​
</script>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfFKw/)